# Crawled/Managed property for List Title?

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property

I have a search query that returns list items. I would like to show the title of the list along with the properties of the item.

Is the list title a crawled or managed property? (The site title is mapped to "SiteTitle" but I cannot find anything for the list.)

Answer (score 2):

The list title is available in the Title property of for example a view on the list (AllItems.aspx). My research so far show that the Title managed property of AllItems include both the site and list name separated by a -.

So, there is no way to get the list title as part of a list items managed properties today, without adding a column to the list containing the list name itself. It's a bit sad as SiteTitle is a managed property of list items. One would think ListTitle should be as well, but I have yet to discover any crawled property for this.

You can use ListID to use script to look it up, but a bit cumbersome indeed.

Comment: Could something be done with the ParentLink managed property ? It return the whole path of the list for each item...

Comment: The path won't help for the title necessary, as a title can change at any time.